# Java Dependency Injection - How to @Inject into a Callable

Tags: java, struts-1

I have a Struts/J2EE application.

I have a class that creates a callable.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NO_THREADS);
    List<Future<Long>> tripFutureList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Long tripId : tripIds) {
        Callable<Long> callable = new CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation(tripId);
        Future<Long> future = executor.submit(callable);
        tripFutureList.add(future);
    }
    for(Future<Long> future : tripFutureList) {
        try {
            logger.fine("Processed trip auto approval escalation for trip: "+future.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            logger.severe("There was an error processing trip."+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    executor.shutdown();
```

This works, however my problem is when the callable needs to perform its `call()` method, the callable cannot `@Inject` any other classes, i.e. they are `null`. This is because the callable is created with the `new` keyword and looses its DI scope.

**Question**

How do I create the callable to still be able to do Dependency Injection?

More info:

Here is the callable class (the injected `TripAutoApprovalEscalationService` is `null`):

```
public class CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation implements Callable<Long> {

    public CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation() {}

    public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation.class.getName());

    @Inject
    private TripAutoApprovalEscalationService tripAutoApprovalEscalation;

    private Long tripId;

    public CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation(Long tripId) {
        this.tripId = tripId;
    }

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Execute trip for callable: "+tripId);
        return tripAutoApprovalEscalation.performEscalation(tripId);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to 1) create `Callable` 2) do injects on it 3) submit it. What you do is ` Callable<Long> callable = new CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation(tripId);` so no injections will work here.

Comment: @Antoniossss, thanks for the comment, but I don't understand what you mean? I do create the callable with the `new` keyword, then I try inject into it with the `@Inject` annotation. I don't know what you mean by your point 3. Yes, I know the `new` keyword I use stops it from using injections, but my question is how do I get around this.

Comment: No you are not - you create new instance via `new` and expect injections it to work somehow. @Inject is not some sort of magic mambo jumbo that will work out of of the box by itself. It is only a marker which your container uses to detect that what needst to be injected - under the hood its just plain java calling setter or setting field by injection.

Comment: @Antoniossss, I know. That's my question.  I think your answer below will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject it to parent container and simply pass that instance

```
//in your wrapping component
@Resource
private YourInjectableClass injectable;

//and then pass it as ctor arg

Callable<Long> callable = new CallableTripAutoApprovalEscalation(tripId, injectable);
Future<Long> future = executor.submit(callable);
```